# Post value not arriving on live environment

Tags: php, html, post, input

I am working on a website which has a problem on the live environment which works fine on the test environment.

The problem is with this input field:
name="quantity[13500:YTozOntpOjEzODkwO3M6NToiNDcxMzgiO2k6MTM4OTE7czo1OiI0NzE0NCI7aToxMzg5MjtzOjU6IjQ3MTQ4Ijt9]"

On the live environment this doesn't seem to arrive (doesn't show on `print_r($_POST))` while the same type of input field with a shorter name does arrive:

```
name="quantity[12624:YToxOntpOjEzODg5O3M6NToiNDcxMzMiO30=]"
```

On my test environment they both arrive just fine.

Does anyone know how I can solve this? Is it maybe a php / apache setting?

EDIT:
I made a test code, this works on the test but fails on the live:

```
<? print_r($_POST); ?>

<form action="#" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="quantity[13500:YTozOntpOjEzODkwO3M6NToiNDcxMzgiO2k6MTM4OTE7czo1OiI0NzE0NCI7aToxMzg5MjtzOjU6IjQ3MTQ4Ijt9]" value="1" size="1" />
    <input type="text" name="quantity[12624:YToxOntpOjEzODg5O3M6NToiNDcxMzMiO30=]" value="1" size="1" />
    <input type="submit" name="go">
</form>
```

Comment: Are you using Wordpress or is this just a simple form using the post method?

Comment: @Robin provide some example code (HTML / PHP)...

Comment: Post your code pls!

Comment: @PhpDude It's an old opencart system, but it also fails if i execute this script seperately in the root (test.php)

Comment: Does your live server use suhosin? If so, it is most likely this setting, https://suhosin.org/stories/configuration.html#suhosin-post-max-name-length

Comment: @CBroe It indeed runs suhosin, the administrator is going to fix it now. Thanks

Comment: It might rather be the suhosin.post.max_array_index_length setting (that is specifically about the length of the "array index", i.e. the part of the name in square brackets). I have added that as an answer; if that is not it, have your admin check the other settings regarding POST values as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your live server use suhosin?

If so, it is most likely this setting, https://suhosin.org/stories/configuration.html#suhosin-post-max-array-index-length

> suhosin.post.max_array_index_length
>
> Type: Integer
> Default: 64
> Defines the maximum length of array indices for variables registered through a POST request.

Additonally, `suhosin.post.max_totalname_length` might play a role (although that has a default of 256, so for your parameter name as shown that would be fine.)

Comment: we changed:
suhosin.post.max_varname_length,
suhosin.post.max_array_index_length,
suhosin.request.max_varname_length and 
suhosin.request.max_array_index_length